# Grails mongodb map type gives illegalStateException

Tags: java, mongodb, grails, grails-orm

I'm trying to add a Map property to a User Domain

```
class User {
    String id
    String username
    String password
    ....
    Map<String, Follower> followers
    //i've tried also without embeded and got the same error. also tried follower insead of followers
    static embedded = ['followers']
}

class Follower {
    String name
    List<String> interests
}
```

I Have a restful controller the implements the save method

```
@Transactional
@Secured(['permitAll'])
def save(User user){
    user.id = new ObjectId().encodeAsBase64()
    user = user.insert(flush: true)
    respond 
}
```

Sadly i'm getting an exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [com.google.gson.JsonObject] to required type [Follower] for property 'followers[532dbe3b8fef86ebe3e64789]': no matching editors or conversion strategy found Around line 26 ofUserController.groovy
```

line 26 is : user = user.insert(flush: true)

example json request:

```
{
    username : "roy",
    password : "123456",

    followers : {
        "532dbe3b8fef86ebe3e64789" : {
            name : "Roy",
            interests : ["math"]
        }
    }
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Thanks!

Roy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are trying to save JSONObject's as Follower instances. The straight forward way to solve the issue would be to convert those into Follower instances manually:

```
def save(User user){
  user.id = new ObjectId().encodeAsBase64()
  user.followers = user.followers.collect{ new Follower( it ) }
  user = user.insert(flush: true)
  respond 
}
```

if you have more of such cases, you should register a property editor for conversion JSON <-> Follower

Comment: Thanks @injecteer for your response. isn't gson suppose to marshel the json object into Object automaticly? any how i'me getting a GroovyRuntimeException could not find matching constructor. also collect returns a list and not a map but maybe i'm just missing something

Comment: @royB does that mean you're getting a different error now?  If so, could you update the question to reflect this?

Comment: I think gson-parser can not do deep-marshalling of hashmaps. It works smoothly with primitive types only, not more. Your no-constructor exception means, that you need to define a default no-arg constructor in each of your classes